# Strongswan CentOS 7 to Mikrotik Router L2TP VPN "NO_PRPOSAL_CHOSEN"

Tags: vpn, centos7, strongswan, mikrotik, l2tp

I have reviewed existing Q&A on this issue and, maybe there's a hook I'm not seeing, but I don't know what else to try.

I get this output when attempting to launch VPN from CentOS "client":

```
[root@hostname etc]# strongswan up casanova_vpn
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA casanova_vpn[1] to <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (176 bytes)
received packet: from <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (156 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V ]
received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
received XAuth vendor ID
received DPD vendor ID
received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
selected proposal: IKE:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
sending packet: from <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (244 bytes)
received packet: from <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (236 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH N(INITIAL_CONTACT) ]
sending packet: from <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (100 bytes)
received packet: from <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (68 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]
IKE_SA casanova_vpn[1] established between <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[<CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>]...<VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[<VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>]
scheduling reauthentication in 3394s
maximum IKE_SA lifetime 3574s
generating QUICK_MODE request 3035167021 [ HASH SA No KE ID ID ]
sending packet: from <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (300 bytes)
received packet: from <VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>[500] to <CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP>[500] (68 bytes)
parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3361583959 [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
establishing connection 'casanova_vpn' failed
[root@hostname etc]#
```

CentOS /etc/ipsec.conf: (I get it that 3des-sha1-modp1024 are weak. I'll bump up the levels when I get the tunnel working, and eventually migrate to certificates...trying to keep it minimal for debug...)

```
[root@hostname etc]# cat ipsec.conf
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
  # strictcrlpolicy=yes
  # uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

conn %default
  ikelifetime=60m
  keylife=20m
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1
  authby=secret
  ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
  esp=3des-sha1-modp1024!

conn casanova_vpn
  keyexchange=ikev1
  left=%defaultroute
  auto=add
  authby=secret
  type=transport
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/1701
  right=<VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>
[root@breezeview etc]#
```

Tik config:

```
ppp profile:

name="Vultr_vpn" local-address=172.16.101.1 remote-address=172.16.101.2 
     use-mpls=default use-compression=default use-encryption=yes 
     only-one=default change-tcp-mss=default use-upnp=default 
     address-list="" dns-server=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 on-up="" on-down=""

proposal:

 2    name="vultr" auth-algorithms=sha1 enc-algorithms=3des lifetime=1h 
      pfs-group=modp1024 

policy:

 T * group=default src-address=<CENTOS_7_PUBLIC_IP/32> dst-address=\<VPN_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP/32> protocol=all proposal=vultr template=yes
```

So...everything *appears* to line up, in theory. In practice...not so much.

Any insights much appreciated!

Comment: Please pardon the noobery. I have no idea how the bold BIG font was created....I pasted in ascii text!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Posts here use markdown, which is why you get this formatting. A "# " at the beginning of the line indicates a level one header for example and for code formatting you need to indent four spaces at the beginning of a line. Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://serverfault.com/help/formatting) for more information and take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more general information. Have fun!

Comment: Anything logged on the Mikrotik side? `NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN` usually indicates a problem with the algorithm proposal, but that seems to match. However, it might also be a problem with the traffic selectors (e.g. I don't see any mention of ports/protocol in the Mikrotik policy configuration, or that transport mode should be used).

Comment: ecdsa - thanks for that. I'll check it out and post results shortly!

-d-

Comment: Clearly there's something amiss with the router. I tested the configs in a lab environment on a CentOS 7 VM and a mikrotik I just purchased for this testing (arrived and put in lab yesterday) and it worked fine after a few tweaks to ppp user related typos. I'll mark this one solved, since I've proven it can work. Just need to figure out why it doesn't on the production system!